# How to Mirror an object and keeping the Scale to 1 and not -1

Tags: mirror, scale

Let's assume I have a face (object) of a man drawn in Blender.
Now I would like to mirror the face, but not by changing the scale of 1 to -1 or from -1 to 1.

Comment: hello, in what way is it a problem to use a scale of 1 to -1? Also, are you talking about Grease Pencil?

Comment: you can use Ctrl M, Symmetrize, or Mirror modifier for example

Comment: I am trying to export an aircraft model for use in MicroSoft Flight SImulator 2020. MSFS produces errors if the scale is neagtive. "Node 'node26' has negative scale, ignoring negative sign." The result is that parts, connected to node26, are flying around the model in the Simulator.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means, one thing you need to do though is recalculate the normals once you've mirrored with SX-1